# Gradually increase of NSTimer in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

What I am trying to do is increase the speed of an NSTimer in swift to increase the speed of a function gradually without making a million different NSTimers. If there is a way to do that, how do you? And if this is not the correct way of doing that, what would the best way be? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can destroy the timer and re-create it with a different interval when you want to increase its speed.

You can also have a single timer that runs at the fastest possible interval, and then ignore the callback unless time % some_number == 0 then gradually make some_number smaller and smaller.

Comment: Ok, but how do I do that?